# [jersey-servlet]: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, web-service, spring, restful, jersey

Estou tentando subir aplicação no WAS 8.5, porém estou tomando esse erro ao fazer o deploy, e com isso a aplicação não roda.

**WEB.XML**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>br.com.mypack.gestaoacesso.services;br.com.mypack.gestaoacesso.helper.jersey</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**Anotação na classe:**

```
@Path("/AutenticacaoRest")
public class AutenticacaoWsImpl
```

Alguém pode me dizer a causa raiz ou solução para esse problema?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Qual versão do Jersey que você tá usando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 1.19

Comment: Você pode alterar a versão? Se sim, tente colocar essas dependências do pastebin. http://pastebin.com/hi4XvnYW. Tive diversos problemas com o Jersey, com essas dependências funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Beleza, @adelmo00 vou alterar e fazer o teste. Obrigado!

Comment: A alteração funcionou?

Comment: Não, o erro persistiu e ainda explodiu classNotFoundException. Acho que o problema é conflito das bibliotecas embarcadas na aplicação do jersey com as que o WAS ja contém nele.